# Unable to set default document in IIS 8

Tags: windows, iis, server, iis-8

My Application is upgraded to windows 2012 on IIS8. Application functioning is also as expected. However, IIS8 does not provide facility to set separate default document  pointing on different port but referring same virtual directory. Request let me know the solution to configure this on IIS 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on IIS the conclusion is we can set the different default page for two virtual directories directing to same path on IIS8 with changes in ApplicationHost.config and removing the default documents from the web.config in  System.webserver

Comment: STEP 1 : run this command in cmd    appcmd.exe set config "Diretory1name" -section:system.webServer/defaultDocument /+"files.[value='defaultpage1.aspx']" /commit:apphost

Comment: STEP2: Again run command in cmd appcmd.exe set config "Directory2name" -section:system.webServer/defaultDocument /+"files.[value='defaultpage2.aspx']" /commit:apphost

Comment: STEP3:Remove the dafault page tags from web.config in section system.webserver

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS manager Start->run->Inetmgr.
2. Select your server in left pane and double click "Default Document" in IIS section as shown below. Enabling default document feature at server level is needed only if you need default document feature enabled for any new application you add to iis else just enable it to your site/application.
   [image]
3. In right hand pane click enable link if its not enabled as show below.
   [image]
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 for your application.
5. Additionally if your default page (e.g. index.htm) resides at bottom of default document list then you can move it up using action pane located on right side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pankaj but i would like to explain you the exact issue .I created a virtual directory with name test with a path D:\Proj\myapp and default document as login.aspx , now when i create another virtual directory with name test2 with the SAME path  D:\Proj\myapp but with different default document as la_login.aspx then the default document when i browse is chosen from the virtual directory which i created first....in IIS 5 and IIS 6 i am able to get the different default pages but on IIS 8 it is being redirected to the same default document.